# cannot pass arraylist from putParcelable function , error Wrong argument Found ImagesPath required Parceble

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

ImagesPath.java

```
public class ImagesPath {

String path;

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public ImagesPath(){}

public ImagesPath(String path){
    this.path=path;
}
}
```

PathList.java to implement Parcelable interface

```
public class PathList extends ArrayList<ImagesPath> implements Parcelable{

public PathList(){}



public PathList(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

    public PathList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new PathList(in);
    }

    public Object[] newArray(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }
};

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    this.clear();
    //First we have to read the list size
    int size = in.readInt();
    //Reading remember that we wrote first the Name and later the Phone Number.
    //Order is fundamental
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        ImagesPath c = new ImagesPath();
        c.setPath(in.readString());
        this.add(c);
    }
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int size = this.size();

    //We have to write the list size, we need him recreating the list

    dest.writeInt(size);

    //We decided arbitrarily to write first the Name and later the Phone Number.

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ImagesPath c = this.get(i);
        dest.writeString(c.getPath());
    }

}
}
```

MainActivity for adding values in Arraylist

```
    PathList pathList;
    ImagesPath c1;
    c1 = new ImagesPath(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    pathList.add(c1);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
            Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            b.putParcelable("list", c1); // Getting Error over here 2nd Argument should be parcelable required parcealbe and found ImagesPath
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
```

Getting Error when passing ImagesPath object in bundle using putParceable()  method Found ImagesPath required Parcelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you didn't implement `Parcelable` in type `ImagesPath`.

So when you implement it for `ImagesPath` you will no need for implementing it for `ArraList<ImagesPath>` and could use putParcelableArraList method of `Bundle`

```
public class ImagesPath 
{
    String path;

@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

public ImagesPath (Parcel in)
{
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator()
{
     public ImagesPath createFromParcel(Parcel in)
     {
         return new ImagesPath(in);
     }

     public Object[] newArray(int arg0)
     {
         return null;
     }
};

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
{
    String path; = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeString(path);
}
}
```